# Finding the largest list of tuples with distinct elements

Tags: python, list, tuples

Given a list of tuples, I want to find the max amount of tuples in the list where all the elements are distinct.

For example using the list:

```
[('nat', 'ges'), ('wisD', 'ges'), ('wisD', 'ak'), ('dutl', 'fatl')]
```

I need to return the list

```
[('nat', 'ges'), ('wisD', 'ak'), ('dutl', 'fatl')]
```

Because this list has the most amount of tuples from the original list while still having all elements be distinct.

I can't really figure out how to tackle this problem, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Break it up into smaller pieces. Figure out how to get the distinct count of one tuple. Then figure out how to filter the list.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, by parsing through the tuple items and setting a flag if an item is duplicate/unique

```
test_list = [('nat', 'ges'), ('wisD', 'ges'), ('wisD', 'ak'), ('dutl', 'fatl')]
result = [] 
temp = set()
matched_items = set()
for inner in test_list:
    flag = True
    for ele in inner:
        if ele in temp and ele in matched_items:
            flag = False
        else:
            temp.add(ele)
    if flag:
        matched_items.update(inner)      
        result.append(inner)
```